# Make $C^1(\mathbb{R})$ a Banach space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, banach-spaces, uniform-convergence

**Question**: Consider $C^1(\mathbb{R})$ of bounded continuously differentiable function with bounded derivative, equipped with the norm $\|f\|_{C^1}\equiv \sup_{\mathbb{R}}(|f|)+\sup_{\mathbb{R}}(|f'|)$. While it is not a Banach space, I am wondering if we can "make it" a Banach space by intersecting it with $H^1(\mathbb{R})$. My question thus is:

Is the space
$$
 C^1(\mathbb{R})\cap H^1(\mathbb{R})
$$
Banach when equipped with the norm being
$$
\max\left(\|f\|_{C^1},\|f\|_{H^1}\right)?
$$

**Context** I am solving a PDE that was shown to be well-posed on a space very similar to the one above and it would really be useful if it could be a Banach space.

**Reasoning** I am thinking that by making the functions go to zero fast enough at $\pm \infty$, it might make a proof of completeness work out. I understand the proofs for $C^1([a,b])$ rely on the application of uniform convergence on $[a,b]$, which I am not sure how to apply when the interval is $\mathbb{R}$. Perhaps there is a way to make $C^1(\mathbb{R})$ Banach if we simply ask the functions in it converge fast anough to zero at $\pm\infty$?

Comment: Why is $C^1$ with that norm not a Banach space?

Comment: Consider $f(x)=x$. This function has bounded derivative while being unbounded. You want to assume the function is bounded as well? In that case, why is the space not a Banach space?

Comment: @温泽海  Yes, thank you, I added the restriction that the function be bounded. I only proof that $C^1([a,b])$ is Banach and saw that $C^1(\mathbb{R})$ can be made Fréchet. Perhaps I just assumed wrongly that my space is not Banach. I would be happy if it would be Banach without having to intersect it with anything!

Comment: @Jose27 The comment above also is a response to your comment. If $C^1(\mathbb{R})$, with the boundedness conditions is already Banach by itself, it would make things much simpler for me.

Comment: The space $C^1$ wouldn't be Banach if you considered integral norm.

Comment: The space of bounded functions with bounded derivatives is a Banach space when equipped with the norm you indicated.

Comment: @s.harp Is it a simple consequence of other "well-known" results or does one have to prove it from scratch. I am asking because you and others seem completely certain it is without having to make other comments then "it is". My experience explained above does not see to show that it is a well-known fact.

Comment: Show the following: 1) The space of bounded continuous functions (on any topological space) is complete wrt. the uniform norm. 2) If $g_n$ is a sequence of $c^1(\Bbb R)$ functions so that $g_n\to g$ and $g_n'\to f$ uniformly then $g$ is $c^1$ and $g'=f$. 3) combine both steps to get that $c^1_b(\Bbb R)$ is Banach.

Comment: @s.harp Thanks. I really appreciate it. It is simple indeed!